# CNAME query fails, but A query returns CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I'm running into the following situation and am wondering how to properly resolve it:

A nameserver is configured to **not** return CNAME records (not under my control), only if an A record is requested (for the same name) the CNAME is returned in the additional section.

**Question 1**: why would someone configure a DNS server to act like this? It doesn't make sense to me? (asked them several times, never got an answer)

Practical problem: When we resolve a hostname, say `testa.hosta.com`, we query an A record. In the response we get:

```
# query for A of `hosta.com`
testa.hosta.com CNAME testb.hostb.com  TTL=5
testb.hostb.com A     1.2.3.4          TTL=60
```

So we're storing both records in our cache. Since we didn't get the A record we were looking for, we now try a CNAME record. But this one is in the cache, it points to `testb.hostb.com`. Now trying an A record for `testb.hostb.com`, which is also in the cache, so we finally resolve to `1.2.3.4`. So all is fine up till now.

After 5 seconds the TTL of the CNAME expires. Because the data is stale, we need to refresh it. So we query for `testa.hosta.com` CNAME, and this delivers an empty response. Now our lookup is broken...

**Question 2**: is this lookup logic faulty? I went through many rfc's to figure it out, but couldn't find anything. What would the proper lookup order be?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you do something like `dig CNAME hosta.com @DOMAIN_ORGIN` dose it return error? Is it working for say CNAME record test.hosta.com? Keep in mind that serving CNAMEs for domain root is not RFC complaint so most DNS providers won't allow such record at all. (there are tricks like CNAME flattening, but very few providers provide this)

Comment: In answer to question 1, there is likely no good reason at all. CNAME records are often abused as people sometimes forget there's more to DNS than addresses.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to perform a lookup with the type set to CNAME. How are you managing to do this? WHY are you doing it?

Comment: *After 5 seconds the TTL of the CNAME expires. Because the data is stale, we need to refresh it. So we query for hosta.com CNAME, and this delivers an empty response. Now our lookup is broken...* -- This is what your question needs to focus on. The rest is assumptions, up to and possibly including this statement. In all likelihood you are misunderstanding the actual problem. Please provide examples to demonstrate that this is in fact the case. Keep in mind that the recursive server might *temporarily* be unable to answer on the refresh if the auth servers are taking a long time to respond.

Comment: @MichaelHampton because of the shorter TTL value. The only thing that expired after 5 seconds is the CNAME record, all other records are still valid. Hence it tries to refresh that record.
It might be that I shouldn't be doing that and still only should query for the original A record again. But another reason to query specifically for the CNAME is that, if the A record (`hosta.com` in the example) cannot be found, and the recursive server doesn't yet have the CNAME, it might not return it upon the A query. Hence the CNAME must be tried at some point in the resolving process, right?

Comment: @AndrewB I might very well be misunderstanding the problem, totally agree. What "examples to demonstrate that this in fact is the case" should I provide?
This case is an actual problem with a client, with the exact order of events as described in the OP. So what I'm trying to figure out is whether my resolving logic is not resilient enough, or whether the client misconfigured their names. And even then, if they misconfigured their names, what is then the common way (they mention other services work for them) to make my resolving logic more resilient to this type of misconfiguration.

Comment: @Daniel my bad, it actually is not a domain root. Bad example on my behalf. Will update the question.

Comment: How about updating it *with the actual domain names in question*?  It makes the whole thing [much easier to answer](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6574/55514).

Comment: @MadHatter I know, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to disclose those.

Comment: You should giggle heartily at anyone suggesting such a restriction, then ignore it.  Meanwhile, I'm voting to close on the grounds of insufficient information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Q1

I have no idea why, that rather sounds like a broken implementation which returns inconsistent results.

#### Q2

Yes, the logic you describe is faulty; you have no reason to change the query type.

It sounds like what you are actually looking for is the very fundamentals of recursive resolver server behavior.

From [RFC1034 Resolver internals / Algorithm section (5.3.3)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-5.3.3):

> ###5.3.3. Algorithm
>
> The top level algorithm has four steps:
>
> 1. See if the answer is in local information, and if so return
>    it to the client.
> 2. Find the best servers to ask.
> 3. Send them queries until one returns a response.
> 4. Analyze the response, either:
>
>    a. if the response answers the question or contains a name
>    error, cache the data as well as returning it back to
>    the client.
>
>    b. if the response contains a better delegation to other
>    servers, cache the delegation information, and go to
>    step 2.
>
>    c. if the response shows a CNAME and that is not the
>    answer itself, cache the CNAME, change the SNAME to the
>    canonical name in the CNAME RR and go to step 1.
>
>    d. if the response shows a servers failure or other
>    bizarre contents, delete the server from the SLIST and
>    go back to step 3.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I must have skipped over this while being braindead from reading too many of those RFC docs

Answer (score 3):

Based on this information:

> Practical problem: When we resolve a hostname, say hosta.com, we query
>   an A record. In the response we get:

```
# query for A of `hosta.com`
hosta.com CNAME hostb.com  TTL=5
hostb.com A     1.2.3.4    TTL=60
```

This is entirely expected. If you query for an `A` record, but only get a `CNAME` back (as shown in this blurb you posted) that indicates that there is no `A` record for that domain, but instead it is a `CNAME` to a different `A` record.

> Question 1: why would someone configure a DNS server to act like this?
>   It doesn't make sense to me? (asked them several times, never got an
>   answer)

As @michaelhampton pointed out, why are you querying for a `CNAME` in the first-place? If you are attempting to perform a host-lookup to resolve a host-name to an IP address, then you should be querying for `A` records. If the owner of the domain has instead opted to use a `CNAME` record for this host-name, then it is appropriate that you will receive the `CNAME` and `A` record back in the response.

**UPDATE:**

> After 5 seconds the TTL of the CNAME expires. Because the data is stale, we need to refresh it. So we query for testa.hosta.com CNAME, and this delivers an empty response. Now our lookup is broken...

This is fine, except you should not be querying the `CNAME` and instead re-query it as an `A` record. The moment your cached value expires, you can no longer assume you know anything about it; you must take the assumption that it's an `A` record and allow the DNS system to perform its work and let it you tell you otherwise.

You should **always** query for `A` records unless you are trying to debug or diagnose something.

Comment: as mentioned in the other comment, if the recursive server doesn't have the CNAME yet, or it temporarily is unavailable, then the resolver logic would, after having failed the A lookup, at some point have to go look for a CNAME anyway right? so somewhere in the process there is in the end a reason to request a CNAME...

Comment: No. The query will continue as an `A` query until the authoritative nameserver responds. The response will be what you see, where it responds stating that the requested hostname is _actually_ a `CNAME` and then will return what the `CNAME` resolves to until an `A` record is returned. Recursive queries are not querying `CNAME`s, they don't know that it's a `CNAME` until an authoritative response says otherwise.

Comment: That makes sense, but not all the way (sorry for being a pita, just trying to learn). Playing devils advocate; recursive server initially resolves 5 second TTL and returns them to me. After 5 seconds the server should discard the CNAME (expired). But the missing response for the A record for `testa.hosta.com` is cached longer (negative cache from SOA). So when my client requeries the A record, then according to specs I'd expect an empty response. Since caching TTL is based on records not answers. (and no lookups to the authoritative server). So still might have to do a CNAME query

Comment: @Tieske The recursive server cannot just randomly change the query type, the client did not ask for `CNAME`. What if the name is no longer an alias, then it would sit there with a negative response for something no one has asked it to look up. Also, there was never a negative response for `testa.hosta.com A` in your scenario, so that cannot possibly have been cached. Ie, when the `CNAME` expires from the cache, the `testa.hosta.com A` query will be made again as needed, and if nothing has changed in that zone it will get that same `CNAME` response again and cache that.